# Moq - Generic set up don't return expected value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am new to Moq, here I have two setups.

```
var settingsMock = new Mock<IECSConfigSettings>();
settingsMock.Setup(m => m.GetRootValue("ss", It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("aaa");
```

And another one is

```
private static void BuildSettingCacheForMock<T>(Mock<IECSConfigSettings> mock, string key, T value)
    {
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetRootValue<T>(key, It.IsAny<T>())).Returns(value);
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetValue<T>(key, It.IsAny<T>())).Returns(value);
        mock.Setup(m => m.TryGetValue<T>(key, out value)).Returns(true);
        mock.Setup(m => m.TryGetRootValue<T>(key, out value)).Returns(true);
    }
var settingsMock = new Mock<IECSConfigSettings>();
BuildSettingCacheForMock<string>(settingsMock, "sss", "aaa1");
```

Finally when I invoke both of them

```
var s1 = new SettingsETag(settingsMock.Object, etag: "ETag", null).Settings.GetRootValue("ss"); // gives "aaa"
var s2 = new SettingsETag(settingsMock.Object, etag: "ETag", null).Settings.GetRootValue("sss"); // gives null
```

Interface details
[Interface code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPnWH.png)

I do not know what is the differences between these and why the result for the second one is null. Appreciate your thoughts on this!

Comment: Please add (relevant parts of) the interface definition as text, not image.

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a return value for the specific call `settingsMock.Setup(m => m.GetRootValue("ss", It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("aaa");` - that is when called with the key "ss", no other values. The second call does not have a set up return value, so you get the default return value `null`.

In general I think it helps to create mocks with `MockBehavior.Strict`. This gives you information about unexpected calls when running your unit tests. The constructor looks like this;

```
var settingsMock = new Mock<IECSConfigSettings>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

If you want to return the same value regardless of the parameter value you can use `It.IsAny<string>()` for the first parameter too.

```
settingsMock.Setup(m => m.GetRootValue(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("aaa");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I do intend to set up a return value in BuildSettingCacheForMock function, and I called it before the invocation of the actual call. But not sure why program treat it as no set up.

Comment: If you try the Strict behavior you will see that you have not setup a return value for your second call. You have only setup the call `m.GetRootValue("ss", [any value])`

Comment: yeah, but I am confused, shouldn't BuildSettingCacheForMock<string>(settingsMock, "sss", "aaa1"); set up the call already?

Comment: It only sets up the call for that specific parameter value ("ss"). Every other parameter value will give you null. If you want a setup for all values you need to write `It.IsAny<string>()` instead of "ss" in the setup.

Comment: In the second way of setting the mock up, the BuildSettingCacheForMock function calls 
mock.Setup(m => m.GetRootValue<T>(key, It.IsAny<T>())).Returns(value), so if I invoke it with ("sss", "aaa1"), "sss" should also gets setup for that mock, right?

Comment: Either use `MockBehavior.Strict` to find out where your problem is (the code won't run if you haven't provided all setups) or edit your question to show a minimal reproducible example.